# Powershell invoke-command with PSCredential in line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to be able to run a command on another server. This script acts as a bootstrap to another script which is run on the actual server. This works great on servers on the same domain, but if I need to run this script on a remote server, I need to specify credentials.

The command is kicked off from a Msbuild targets file like so:

```
  <Target Name="PreDeployment" Condition="true" BeforeTargets="MSDeployPublish">

    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command bootstrapScript.ps1 -computername $(MyServer) -argumentlist param1, param2" />

  </Target>
```

However, I need to be able to supply the credentials by creating a new PSCredentials object with a secure password for my deployment script to run on a remote server:

```
<Target Name="PreDeployment" Condition="true" BeforeTargets="MSDeployPublish">          
        <Exec Command="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command bootstrapScript.ps1 -computername $(MyServer) -credential New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('admin', (convertto-securestring $(Password) -asplaintext -force)) -argumentlist param1, param2" />
  </Target>
```

When I run the build, a dialog pops up with the username set to System.Management.Automation.PSCredential.
I need to be able to create the credentials in-line on the executable target.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting parens around the instantiation of the PSCredential object e.g.:

```
... -credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'admin',(convertto-securestring $(Password) -asplaintext -force)) -argumentlist param1, param2" />
```

PowerShell parsing tends to interpret arguments as literal strings (or numbers).  If you want to evaluate an expression you usually put the expression inside parens. This is known as a grouping expression in PowerShell.